# How to import Blender mesh+rig separately from animations for generic rigs in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, import

Currently I'm creating mesh, rig and animations in Blender and export them together as an fbx file.
I know that importing animations separately works for humanoid meshes, but how to do this for  a generic rig?

### Why?

After importing a character, I have to add components to some bone game objects of the characters rig. Adding or changing animations of an already existing character currently requires me to reimport mesh+rig aswell as the animations and then add the components to those game objects again.

Also sometimes the reference of existing prefabs to the reimported mesh is lost and I have to add the mesh to those prefabs again, this might have been me doing somethin wrong though.

### Better solution?

I also thought about naming bones in blender in a certain way and have a script in Unity add these components, I would still prefer to import animations separately though.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the prefab approach you describe is a good solution here. If you can walk us through specific repro steps to demonstrate the problem where the prefabs lose their mesh reference, we can try t help you solve that glitch.

Comment: Ok had to delete my previous comment bc I submitted by accident and took too long to edit (stupid small android keyboard..). I originaly didnt think about how prefabs would solve this but I think I do now. Ill update the question when/if I find repro steps for the reference loss. Thanks for your comment :>